# password-hash-and-salt password verification fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, passwords

I'm using the nodeJS password-hash-and-salt library to encrypt password which I then store in a DB. This works fine. The problem comes in when I try to verify the password. Looking at the documentation, it should be simple... The example works flawlessly, but verifying a hash which was previously stored in a DB is failing. I've verified that the hash is not changing in-database, and that the hash is been returned when queried... I've also hashed a string and then tried to verify that string using the same string in-code (with no variables). I must be doing SOMETHING wrong... Anyone have any ideas? (Code below, library link here https://github.com/florianheinemann/password-hash-and-salt)

```
verifyPassword  = function(user,pw){
    // Connect to db
    myuser = {};
    var con = connect();
    // Run query
    con.query('SELECT UID,password FROM users WHERE username = ?', user, function(err,res){
        if(err){ throw err; }
        else  { 
              myuser.userID = res[0].UID;
              myuser.pswdV = res[0].password;          

        // Verifying hash 
            //console.log(pw);
            //console.log(myuser.pswdV);
            password(pw).verifyAgainst(myuser.pswdV, function(error, verified) {
                //console.log(verified);
                if(error)
                    throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
                if(!verified) {
                    //socket.emit('popError','Invalid username or password. Please check your password and try again.');
                    //return {err:'Invalid username or password. Please check your password and try again.'}
                    console.log('Not verified');
                } else {
                    var token = crypto.randomBytes(64);
                    token = buf.toString('hex');
                    myuser.secret = token;
                    delete myuser.pswdV;
                    con.query('UPDATE users SET magicSecret = ? WHERE username = ?', [token,user], function(err,res){ 
                        if(err) { 
                                    socket.emit('popError','Failed to login, this is a server problem.'); 
                                    //return {err:'Failed to login, this is a server problem.'}
                                }
                        else    { 
                                    socket.emit('login_success',myuser); 
                                    // return {err:myuser}
                                }
                    });                    
                }
            });
        }    
    });
    con.end(function(err) {
      // The connection is terminated gracefully
      // Ensures all previously enqueued queries are still
      // before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.
    }); 
};
```

Please excuse the debugging code... This should give you an idea of what I'm trying to do. If you see why it's failing please let me know.

Comment: You didn't say where does this fail, and what error message you get?

Comment: It doesn't specifically fail. Rather, it logs "Not verified." That's currently what it's set to do when a password can't be verified, but it's always going down that path rather than accepting the correct password(s).

Comment: Hmm. Was the original password hashed on the same machine (not sure if it would make a difference). Also, does your "password" in the database have the format `pbkdf2$10000$SOMETHING$SOMETHING_ELSE`?

Comment: @Zlatko, 
Yes sir. Same machine, same instance... And in the DB it does indeed have that format.